# Is maximal spectral entropy of residuals a poor loss function because phase information is lost?

Tags: regression, entropy, spectral-analysis

Suppose I define a custom loss function `SpectralEntropy` as follows:

```py
class SpectralEntropy(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        result = y_true - y_pred
        result = tf.signal.rfft(result)
        result = tf.abs(result)
        result = tf.math.pow(result, 2)
        result = result / tf.cast(len(result), tf.float32)
        result = result / tf.reduce_sum(result)
        result = result * tf.math.log(result)
        result = tf.reduce_sum(result)
        return result
```

In a simple linear regression problem of $Y = 5X + 10 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, I find the plot of the predicted and true values appear to differ by a constant:

[image]

The above plot was for $10^4$ epochs. It seems like the intercept might be drifting. Here is an example with $10^3$ epochs which appears to be closer:

[image]

Because this effect is quite consistent, and my code is probably correct, I suspect there is a mathematical reason for this. My suspicion is that because the Fourier transform is forgetful of the phase that there is no gradient update to the intercept.

Is this suspicion correct?

---

More evidence: I tried adjusting the loss function by adding $(\mathbb{E}[Y] - \mathbb{E}[\hat Y])^2$ just to help it find the right translation. Here is the custom loss function:

```py
class SpectralEntropyMean(tf.keras.losses.Loss):

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        result = y_true - y_pred
        result = tf.signal.rfft(result)
        result = tf.abs(result)
        result = tf.math.pow(result, 2)
        result = result / tf.cast(len(result), tf.float32)
        result = result / tf.reduce_sum(result)
        result = result * tf.math.log(result)
        result = tf.reduce_sum(result)
        result = result + tf.math.pow(tf.reduce_mean(y_true) - tf.reduce_mean(y_pred), 2)
        return result
```

And now the model seems to have remarkably good fit:

[image]

So the entropy part alone may have successfully estimated the slope of the line, but not the intercept. And the entropy plus the square different in means provided the needed intercept (which alone wouldn't learn the slope of the line).

Comment: I have tried a few different optimizers (e.g. Adam, RMSProp, AdaGrad).

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43470/why-phase-information-is-usually-ignored-after-fourier-transform

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3228080

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17095/why-does-the-fourier-series-not-include-phase-information

Comment: From the links I have added in the comments, I am mistaken in thinking that phase information is lost in the Fourier transform in general. But perhaps something else I am doing (differencing, calculating spectral power, etc) is removing phase.

Comment: I answered a related type of question here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114486/135267